# Need Status delete function guidance

Tags: php, social-networking, status

I need help with adding a delete status function. I need to know if my delete button is in the right place and what I need to put in my delete.php page for a users comment to be deleted out of my database and from the user feed.

I've heard this is pretty simple to do. But I just can't get my head around it, its something I've never actually done. So I'd just like the user to press the X and the popup to link to the delete.php and if accepted to delete by the user it removes that comment from both the stream and obviously the database.

Here is my STREAMFULL.PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                                function show_confirm()
                                                {
                                                var r=confirm("are you sure you want to delete?");
                                                if (r==true)
                                                  {
                                                  window.location="http://www.fightstar.org/raw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php'";
                                                  }
                                                else
                                                  {
                                                  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
                                                  }
                                                }
                                                </script>'

<style>

<?php


            while($streamitem_data = mysql_fetch_array($chant)){
                echo "<div class='stream_object'>";
                echo "<table style='word-wrap: break-word;'><td valign='top' style='word-wrap: break-word;padding:5px;'>";
                echo "<img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;' src='";sn_user_core::output_profile_image_url($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']);echo "' onerror='this.src=\"sn-admin/css/img/no_profile_img.jpeg\";'><td valign=top>";
                    $poster_name = sn_user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']);
                    $target_name = sn_user_core::getuser($streamitem_data['streamitem_target']);
                    $cont = stripslashes($streamitem_data['streamitem_content']);

                    if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==2)){
                    $cont = htmlentities($cont);
                    $cont = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a class='user_link' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $cont);

                    }

                    if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
                        echo "<a href='sn-profile.php?uid=".$poster_name['id']."'>" . $poster_name['firstname']." ".$poster_name['lastname'] ."</a>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<a href='sn-profile.php?uid=".$poster_name['id']."'>" .$poster_name['firstname']." ".$poster_name['lastname'] ." </a>  
                        >
                              <a href='sn-profile.php?uid=".$target_name['id']."'>" .$target_name['firstname']." ".$target_name['lastname'] ."</a>";
                    }

                    if($streamitem_data['streamitem_type_id']==2){
                    $cont = nl2br($cont);
                    echo "<div style='display:inline;'> ".$cont." </div>";
                    }else{

                        if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$streamitem_data['streamitem_target']){
                        $cont = nl2br($cont);
                            echo "<div>".$cont."</div>";
                        }else{
                        $cont = nl2br($cont);
                        echo "<div>".$cont."</div>";
                        }

                    }
                echo "<div class='post_contextoptions'>";

                                echo "<div class='stream_option'>".Agotime($streamitem_data['streamitem_timestamp']);
                                    if(!($streamitem_data['streamitem_viaid']==0)){


                    //COMMENTS

                        echo '<a href=""  onclick="show_confirm()" alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="delete">X</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your script doesn't do anything but redirect the user to a 'delete.php' page if they hit confirm. You need to embed some sort of identifier to show which comment they click the delete button for. That'd make the url look like `http://example.com/delete.php?commentID=123`. The delete script would retrieve the comment ID and do whatever it has to.

That's about as far as I'll go. I'm not going to read through your wall of code to figure out what you're trying to do. While showing code is always welcome, that's way too much. Distill it down to a representative sample of what you're trying to do. We want the Cliff's Notes versions, not the full War & Peace.

Comment: Ok Marc. But if I just add commentID=123 won't it just delete comment 123 and not say a comment of 122 that the user clicks on.. I will cut out the parts now that are irrelevant.

Comment: Ok I've done an edit and cut it down to just the comments with the javascript

Comment: Well, you'd fill in the comment ID dynamically. 123 is just an example.

Comment: Dynamically?? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Your code sample is still way to big for me to read, andit's been a long day. Basically, in whatever bit of code you generate the comments, you must have the comment's identifier available. Output a button or link with the delete url and that identifier.

Comment: So this is my dynamic 

/delete.php?commentID='.$row1['comment_id'].'

Comment: Yes, exactly. fill in a unique value for each comment in each copy of the delete link you do. But be careful making it a simple link: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What's so difficult about it?

Start Situtation: You have a comment in the database

Next:

1. User identifies
2. User browses to a show my comments page
3. Show my comments page is displaye, for example a list with comment previews which are        clickable and already bounded with the primary key, like:

   a href=somepage?comm_id=$res[0]>substr($res[1],0,50) /a

where $res is an array with results from mysql and $res[0] is the value for primary key and $res[1] is the a preview of the comment.
4. After a comment is clicked you still have the id of it, so  display this comment in a new page with edit,  delete whatever buttons like this:

```
<form .... action=delete.php>
<input type=button name=edit value=edit>
<input type=button name=delete value=delete>
<input type=hidden name=comment_id value=$_GET['comm_id']>
</form>
```

where $_GET[comm_id] came from the previous page.

At this point you can select to go the traditional way or http request for calling delete.php

1. Once you have the delete.php alive it goes like:

   if(isset($_POST['delete']))
      delete($_POST['comment_id'])
   ...etc

and the delete function just goes like:

```
...etc
$sql='delet...etc where `id`='.$_POST['comment_id']
...etc
```

on success show some page on failure some other...

Of course no security, sql attack prevention is not given here, this is your work.. it's just a basic scenario.

You always want to make things as musch automated as possible, data cleaning, sql insertions, queries etc all make a perfect ground for automating things!

Comment: Ok, Melsi, you have got me closer, I click the delete button and it shows the id in the browser. 

This is the delete button 
echo '<a href="mysite/raw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].'  onclick="show_confirm()" alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="delete">X</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

And the result
mysite/raw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?=1503

But when it navigates to delete.php it says comment not found, so maybe I have errors in the delet.php page now.

Comment: In such cases you always split and isolate things. Example of debugging scenario:

Answer (score 0):

Do in your site:

```
1.Echo the sql in the page(just for testing)
2.Copy the id
```

Do all the following in mysql client (heidisql is free)

```
2.Paste sql to the sql editor,click the execute button (is a blue one)
5.after you make the sql working 100% check results
6.1 A result is returned then ok leave the client
6.2 A result is not returned you can view the data of the  table (click data tab) copy an existing value paste it to the sql editor and now the query must return this record
```

This ways you know where you should focus or where the problem was:
-The query
-The wrong id
etc

In general often needed to echo sql and run it directly from client when still on developement. Successful debugging often requires for isolating and testing things individually. In php the most common-simple tools for debuggin are combinations of:

```
print_r [you see the structure of sth]
var_dump [in addition show type of, int, str etc]
echo [if hello is echoed this means the code reaches at certain point]
if(true){echo 'hello';} [if hello is echoed then the condition inside if was the problem]
echo 'hello'; exit; [you don't care for the rest you want to check up to hello]
die('hello') [fast way for echo 'string';exit; die does not work well with int die(332)]
```

Attention: take a few basic sequrity measures.
1. Any logged in user can delete someone's else comment while changing the id on the url so before you delet a comment make sure at least that the comment to be deleted matches the logged in user, for example pseudo code:
if row exist where comment id=logged in user id return true else return false
if true delete if false do not delete
2. Whenever possible go the PDO way, if it is properly used can help in sql injection attacks.
3. can use post when possible insted of get, if you search about php security there is a lot available.